Why are files read only?
Why are files read only?
My system is dual boot, Ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, and Windows 10
This problem only started recently, after the last Ubuntu update.
In the morning when I first log in and open a file with 'Text Editor', it opens as 'read only'.
The file is on a different partition (not the Windows partition).
When I check the file in Windows, the 'read only' bit is NOT set.
I run the Windows command to unset it anyway (ATTRIB -R-H F:*.* /S/D).
It then opens in Ubuntu allowing me to edit it.

There are multiple reasons incluing: read-only file systems (e.g. mounted read only, read only media like CDROMs) and Unix file permissions won't be editable from within Windows

Was the disk in question last used on a Windows system with the "Fast boot" setting enabled?
The Windows "Fast Boot" (Windows defaults to "ON") setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

waltinator - I think you're right.  I didn't think that ending the day in windows would affect how Ubuntu behaved the next morning (after the computer being shut down for the night. Last night I ended the day in Ubuntu and this morning the files were not read only. Thanks
